# Help with particles

Tags: particles

I've been given the following sentences, and I'm supposed to fill in the blankets with particles.

1. Katō-san wa getsu-yōbi (  ) ka-yōbi (  ) Nihon (  ) kaerimasu.
2. Atama ga itai desu (  ) netsu (  ) arimasu (  ) kaze da (  ) omoimasu.

Here are my attempts:

1. Katō-san wa getsu-yōbi **mo** ka-yōbi **ga** Nihon **ni** kaerimasu.
2. Atama ga itai desu **o** netsu **o** arimasu **ga** kaze da **o** omoimasu.

What particles should I use?

Comment: Could you show us your own attempt first? And.. are you sure it's "kaze **de** ", not "kaze **da** "?

Comment: Apologies, it is "kaze da".. and what I've come up with is "Katō san wa getsu-yōbi mo ka-yōbi ga Nihon ni kaerimasu" but for the second one, I'm not sure..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question 1: Katō san wa getsu-yōbi (１) ka-yōbi (２) Nihon (３) kaerimasu.**
>   Your answer: Katō san wa getsu-yōbi (も) ka-yōbi (が) Nihon (に) kaerimasu.
>   My answer: Katō san wa getsu-yōbi (か) ka-yōbi (に) Nihon (へ) kaerimasu.

- に in (3) also makes sense, so your answer is correct.
- You can't depart to Japan at the same time on Monday and also on Tuesday, so (1) couldn't be も.
- As for (2), if you use が there, then the phrase becomes like "ka-yobi is going to return to Japan". It's not ka-yobi but Katō-san that is going to return to Japan.

> **Question 2: Atama ga itai desu (４) netsu (５) arimasu (６) kaze da (７) omoimasu.**
>   Your answer: Atama ga itai desu (を) netsu (を) arimasu (<del>が</del>か) kaze da (<del>を</del>と) omoimasu.
>   My answer: Atama ga itai desu (＊) netsu (＊) arimasu (＊＊) kaze da (と) omoimasu.

I suggest you first think of a logical English translation for your answer *Atama ga itai desu (を) netsu (を) arimasu (が) kaze da (を) omoimasu* by consulting the following hints:

- Atama ga itai desu ([4]{L}) = I have a headache [and]{LLL}
- netsu (5) arimasu ([ 6 ]{LLL}) = I have a fever, and [therefore]{LLLLLLLLL}
- kaze [da(7)]{LLLLL} omoimasu. = I guess/think [that]{LLLL} I have a cold.

Comment: alright, I'll try my best! Question 2: Atama ga itai desu (を) netsu (を) arimasu (が) kaze da (を) omoimasu. Also, thank you very much!

Comment: @Dominique Are you aware that が is a subject particle? *arimasu* is an intransitive verb literally meaning "to exist", so what's its subject? And, to connect a quoted phrase/sentence and *omoimasu* you need a quotative particle.

Comment: @Chocolate Ah, I see.. So instead of が I'll use か? And for the quotation particle, will と be the correct choice?

Comment: Wait, on second thought, "netsu *mo* arimasu" is better than "netsu *ga* arimasu" here, no? So... it'd be like, "I *also* have a fever, so...", right?

Comment: @Dominique Yes! と is the quotative particle to be followed by omoimasu here :)

Comment: @Chocolate Apologies if I'm quite a bother, but could you please explain why 'mo' would be a better choice for the context?

Comment: @Dominique *mo* means "also/too". "Netsu ga arimasu" would be just "I have a fever", but "netsu *mo* arimasu" would be "(I have a headache, and adding to that,) I *also* have a fever", "I have a fever, *too* ."

Comment: @Chocolate ohh, I see :) I'll make sure to take note of that! So the sentence would be: 'Atama ga itai desu (o) netsu (mo) arimasu (ka) kaze da (to) omoimasu'?

Comment: @Dominique Have you learned the conjunctive particle ~し ("and" or "so") that connects verbs, verb phrases or sentences? and the conjunctive particle ~から ("because~" or "~so") for stating a reason?